# Can't access Tomcat launched in Docker container

Tags: tomcat, docker, portforwarding

I'm launching Tomcat as a Docker container:

```
$ docker run -dP tomcat
```

And the process starts correctly:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
48b87e545c18        tomcat              "catalina.sh run"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp   hopeful_ardinghelli

$ docker logs 48b87e545c18
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.027 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.037 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 18 2015 11:38:37 UTC
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.037 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.26.0
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.0.9-boot2docker
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b14
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.041 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.041 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.043 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.043 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.044 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.044 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.226 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.267 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.272 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.274 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.282 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1251 ms
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.325 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.341 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
16-Sep-2015 17:16:38.374 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
16-Sep-2015 17:17:16.231 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [36,979] milliseconds.
16-Sep-2015 17:17:16.276 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 37,901 ms
16-Sep-2015 17:17:16.276 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs
16-Sep-2015 17:17:16.361 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 85 ms
16-Sep-2015 17:17:16.362 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.221 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 859 ms
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.343 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 101 ms
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.354 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.452 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 98 ms
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.460 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.484 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Sep-2015 17:17:17.487 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 39204 ms
```

But when I hit the server in the browser at the URL `http://localhost:32769`, I get a connection refused error. I also tried to publish ports explicitly:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8888:8080 tomcat
```

Or launch the container in interactive shell mode:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8080 tomcat
```

But neither helped: `http://localhost:8888` refuses the connection. How would I go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this on a DigitalOcean Docker VM:

```
root@33b54c81-d980-41a4-982a-f0449663b68e:~# docker run -dP tomcat
Unable to find image 'tomcat:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/tomcat
843e2bded498: Pull complete 
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for tomcat:latest
41cea0a1fede58d066af0f6ce5fc17aef66d4b4912244cf4966b5f459b881e1b
```

Container running:

```
root@33b54c81-d980-41a4-982a-f0449663b68e:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
41cea0a1fede        tomcat              "catalina.sh run"        2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32768->8080/tcp   mad_panini
```

Testing via `docker-proxy` host port mapping:

```
root@33b54c81-d980-41a4-982a-f0449663b68e:~# telnet localhost 32768
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: localhost

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
...
```

Note, `Docker` also punches a hole in `iptables` which allows direct communication with containers (without the host port mapping):

```
root@33b54c81-d980-41a4-982a-f0449663b68e:~# iptables -L
...
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ALLOW      all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.1           tcp dpt:http-alt
```

Testing direct:

```
root@33b54c81-d980-41a4-982a-f0449663b68e:~# telnet 172.17.0.1 8080
Trying 172.17.0.1...
Connected to 172.17.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: localhost

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
...
```

You can also experiment with passing `--net=host` argument to `docker run`, which exposes the host's networking directly to the container.

Hope this helps..

-- ab1

Comment: Great, thanks! You taught me something new. Although my problem was I tried to hit the server on `localhost`, while the default docker machine was mapped to a different network interface -__-

Answer (score 1):

The port mapping is performed on the address of the default machine which was `192.168.99.100`. The URLs were `http://192.168.99.100:32769` and `http://192.168.99.100:8888` respectively. Hope this helps others encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running docker with boot2docker you have to launch tomcat using the boot2docker VM ip address.

You can get the ip address with the following command:

```
boot2docker ip
```

Then run http://ip_address:8888

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't use the localhost to access your docker address.
You have to use the IP that is relates with your virtual network.
You have to check what subnet your docker is running.

Example: The ip address of my notebook is 192.168.1.13 but the IP address of my VirtualMachine where is running 192.168.99.100.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have any proxy set in your machine which is also getting applied for localhost.

**How can I check:** 
With the command `printenv` , check if you have any http_proxy or https_proxy defined and `no_proxy` is not defined.